# Change current time in Vimeo video player with Vue/Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vimeo

i'm using this library https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vue-vimeo-player/tree/master to embed vimeo player in Vue+Nuxt application but with my own custom controls, everything is working fine expect i can't find a way how to change current time of player. I already have time where i want to switch, but i cannot find a method to achive this. For exmaple in Youtube IFrame API there is a method called `player.seekTo(nextTime)`. Also i now from here https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/reference that Vimeo SDK provide a method `setCurrentTime(seconds)`, but i don't know how i can use it with vue-vimeo-player library.

This is my code for player component:

```
<vimeo-player
    ref="player"
    :video-id="videoId"
    :controls="false"
    :autoplay="true"
    :options="{ responsive: true }"
    @playing="isPlaying = true"
    @pause="isPlaying = false"
    @ended="closeFullWindow"
    @timeupdate="onProgress"
  />
```

And method when user click my custom time control:

```
lineClicked ({ clientX }) {
  //...calculations to get nextTime...
  // Here i have my time where user clicked:
  console.log('nextTime', nextTime)

  // Here is method from Vimeo SDK but how use it with vue-vimeo-player?
  // this.player.setCurrentTime(30.456).then(function (seconds) {
  //   // `seconds` indicates the actual time that the player seeks to
  // }).catch(function (error) {
  //   switch (error.name) {
  //     case 'RangeError':
  //       // The time is less than 0 or greater than the video's duration
  //       break

  //     default:
  //       // Some other error occurred
  //       break
  //   }
  // })

  // With Youtube IFrame API all i had to do is:
  // this.player.seekTo(nextTime)
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i find out that vue-vimeo-player is based on this https://github.com/vimeo/player.js so basically what i had to do is: `this.$refs.player.player.setCurrentTime(nextTime)`